# How to fix error with PIP Install Couchbase in Python 3.9.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, scripting, couchbase

I am having issues trying to install the couchbase python module and can't seem to find a working solution online.

Please note that I have previously installed this version (2.5.11) of the module on a different machine running python 3.8.x and Windows 10, but I get errors when trying to install it on a new machine with running python 3.9.1 and Windows 10.

I have tried the following to see if it would fix the issue:

```
python pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

and

```
pip install docutils
```

The complete (sanitized) error output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\USERNAME>pip install couchbase==2.5.11
Collecting couchbase==2.5.11
  Using cached couchbase-2.5.11.tar.gz (591 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: couchbase
  Building wheel for couchbase (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3_475qvt\\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3_475qvt\\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-avdmzikj'
       cwd: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3_475qvt\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\
  Complete output (147 lines):
  C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3_475qvt\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\setup.py:111: UserWarning: I'm detecting you're running windows.You might want to modify the 'setup.py' script to use appropriate paths
    warnings.warn("I'm detecting you're running windows."
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase
  copying acouchbase\asyncio_iops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase
  copying acouchbase\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase
  copying acouchbase\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\admin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\analytics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\analytics_ingester.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\auth_domain.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\bucketmanager.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\cbas.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\cluster.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\connection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\connstr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\crypto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\deprecation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\experimental.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\fulltext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\items.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\mockserver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\mutation_state.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\n1ql.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\priv_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\result.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\subdocument.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\transcoder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\user_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\_bootstrap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\_ixmgmt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\_logutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\_pyport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  copying couchbase\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\views
  copying couchbase\views\iterator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\views
  copying couchbase\views\params.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\views
  copying couchbase\views\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\views
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\iops
  copying couchbase\iops\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\iops
  copying couchbase\iops\select.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\iops
  copying couchbase\iops\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\iops
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
  copying couchbase\asynchronous\async_bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
  copying couchbase\asynchronous\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
  copying couchbase\asynchronous\events.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
  copying couchbase\asynchronous\fulltext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
  copying couchbase\asynchronous\n1ql.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
  copying couchbase\asynchronous\rowsbase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
  copying couchbase\asynchronous\view.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
  copying couchbase\asynchronous\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
  copying couchbase\tests\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
  copying couchbase\tests\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
  copying couchbase\tests\test_sync.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
  copying couchbase\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\admin_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\analytics_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\append_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\arithmetic_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\badargs_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\cbftstrings_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\cluster_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\connection_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\connstr_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\crypto_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\datastructures_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\delete_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\design_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\diag_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\dupkeys_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\empty_key_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\encodings_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\endure_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\enh_err_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\excextra_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\flush_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\format_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\get_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\iops_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\itertypes_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\itmops_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\ixmgmt_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\lockmode_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\lock_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\misc_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\mutationtokens_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\n1qlstrings_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\n1ql_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\observe_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\pipeline_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\results_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\rget_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\set_converters_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\set_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\spatial_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\stats_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\subdoc_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\touch_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\tracing_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\transcoder_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\verinfo_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\viewstrings_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\view_iterator_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\view_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\xattr_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  copying couchbase\tests\cases\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
  copying gcouchbase\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
  copying gcouchbase\connection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
  copying gcouchbase\gevent_bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
  copying gcouchbase\iops_gevent0x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
  copying gcouchbase\iops_gevent10.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
  copying gcouchbase\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
  copying txcouchbase\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
  copying txcouchbase\connection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
  copying txcouchbase\iops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
  copying txcouchbase\twisted_bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
  copying txcouchbase\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
  package init file 'acouchbase\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
  copying acouchbase\tests\asyncio_tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
  copying acouchbase\tests\fixtures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
  copying acouchbase\tests\py34only.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
  copying acouchbase\tests\py35only.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
  package init file 'acouchbase\py34only\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\py34only
  copying acouchbase\py34only\iterator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\py34only
  copying couchbase\libcouchbase.dll -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
  running build_ext
  building 'couchbase._libcouchbase' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 -I..\lcb-winbuild\x64\deps\include -Ic:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc\bucket.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\bucket.obj
  bucket.c
  c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3_475qvt\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\src\pycbc.h(193): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for couchbase
  Running setup.py clean for couchbase
Failed to build couchbase
Installing collected packages: couchbase
    Running setup.py install for couchbase ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3_475qvt\\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3_475qvt\\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1zzxrwpq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\couchbase'
         cwd: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3_475qvt\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\
    Complete output (147 lines):
    C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3_475qvt\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\setup.py:111: UserWarning: I'm detecting you're running windows.You might want to modify the 'setup.py' script to use appropriate paths
      warnings.warn("I'm detecting you're running windows."
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase
    copying acouchbase\asyncio_iops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase
    copying acouchbase\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase
    copying acouchbase\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\admin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\analytics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\analytics_ingester.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\auth_domain.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\bucketmanager.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\cbas.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\cluster.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\connection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\connstr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\crypto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\deprecation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\experimental.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\fulltext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\items.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\mockserver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\mutation_state.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\n1ql.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\priv_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\result.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\subdocument.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\transcoder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\user_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\_bootstrap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\_ixmgmt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\_logutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\_pyport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    copying couchbase\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\views
    copying couchbase\views\iterator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\views
    copying couchbase\views\params.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\views
    copying couchbase\views\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\views
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\iops
    copying couchbase\iops\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\iops
    copying couchbase\iops\select.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\iops
    copying couchbase\iops\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\iops
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
    copying couchbase\asynchronous\async_bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
    copying couchbase\asynchronous\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
    copying couchbase\asynchronous\events.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
    copying couchbase\asynchronous\fulltext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
    copying couchbase\asynchronous\n1ql.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
    copying couchbase\asynchronous\rowsbase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
    copying couchbase\asynchronous\view.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
    copying couchbase\asynchronous\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\asynchronous
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
    copying couchbase\tests\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
    copying couchbase\tests\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
    copying couchbase\tests\test_sync.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
    copying couchbase\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\admin_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\analytics_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\append_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\arithmetic_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\badargs_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\cbftstrings_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\cluster_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\connection_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\connstr_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\crypto_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\datastructures_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\delete_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\design_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\diag_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\dupkeys_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\empty_key_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\encodings_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\endure_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\enh_err_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\excextra_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\flush_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\format_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\get_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\iops_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\itertypes_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\itmops_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\ixmgmt_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\lockmode_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\lock_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\misc_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\mutationtokens_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\n1qlstrings_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\n1ql_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\observe_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\pipeline_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\results_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\rget_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\set_converters_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\set_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\spatial_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\stats_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\subdoc_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\touch_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\tracing_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\transcoder_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\verinfo_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\viewstrings_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\view_iterator_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\view_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\xattr_t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    copying couchbase\tests\cases\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase\tests\cases
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
    copying gcouchbase\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
    copying gcouchbase\connection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
    copying gcouchbase\gevent_bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
    copying gcouchbase\iops_gevent0x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
    copying gcouchbase\iops_gevent10.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
    copying gcouchbase\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gcouchbase
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
    copying txcouchbase\bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
    copying txcouchbase\connection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
    copying txcouchbase\iops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
    copying txcouchbase\twisted_bucket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
    copying txcouchbase\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\txcouchbase
    package init file 'acouchbase\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
    copying acouchbase\tests\asyncio_tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
    copying acouchbase\tests\fixtures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
    copying acouchbase\tests\py34only.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
    copying acouchbase\tests\py35only.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\tests
    package init file 'acouchbase\py34only\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\py34only
    copying acouchbase\py34only\iterator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\acouchbase\py34only
    copying couchbase\libcouchbase.dll -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\couchbase
    running build_ext
    building 'couchbase._libcouchbase' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 -I..\lcb-winbuild\x64\deps\include -Ic:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc\bucket.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\bucket.obj
    bucket.c
    c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3_475qvt\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\src\pycbc.h(193): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3_475qvt\\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3_475qvt\\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1zzxrwpq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\couchbase' Check the logs for full command output.

C:\Users\USERNAME>
```

Comment: I am not running a Windows box, so I can't reproduce. Did you take a look at the error message  `c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3_475qvt\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\src\pycbc.h(193): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h': No such file or directory` ?

Comment: By the way there's a warning about running the installation on Windows `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3_475qvt\couchbase_ffbb6075b7344f3580fc833cec48eea3\setup.py:111: UserWarning: I'm detecting you're running windows.You might want to modify the 'setup.py' script to use appropriate paths`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I checked, the problem is that Couchbase has not yet released a python module that works with this version of Python.

Their fix is to install an earlier version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the prerequisite Couchbase C SDK (libcouchbase) isn't installed or couldn't be found. "**fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h': No such file or directory**"

As per the documentation: https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/2.5/start-using-sdk.html you need to install libcouchbase before installing the 2.x Python SDK to resolve this issue.

I would highly recommend installing the newer 3.x Couchbase Python SDK as this prerequisite is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-pip
```

and run

```
pip install couchbase
```